# hadoop distcp doesnot create folder when we pass single file

Tags: scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, distcp

I am facing below issues in hadoop Distcp any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

I am trying to copy data from Google Cloud platform to Amazon S3

1)  When we have multiple files to copy from source to destination (This work fine)

```
  val sourcefile : String = "gs://XXXX_-abc_account2621/abc_account2621_click_20170616*.csv.gz [Multiple files to copy (we have * in the file name)]

  Output: S3://S3bucketname/xxx/xxxx/clientid=account2621/date=2017-08-18/
  Files in above path
  abc_account2621_click_2017061612_20170617_005852_572560033.csv.gz
  abc_account2621_click_2017061616_20170617_045654_572608350.csv.gz
  abc_account2621_click_2017061622_20170617_103107_572684922.csv.gz
  abc_account2621_click_2017061623_20170617_120235_572705834.csv.gz
```

2)  When we have only one file to copy from source to destination (Issue)

```
    val sourcefile : String = "gs://XXXX_-abc_account2621/abc_account2621_activity_20170618_20170619_034412_573362513.csv.gz

   Output:S3://S3bucketname/xxx/xxxx/clientid=account2621/ 
   Files in above path 
   date=2017-08-18 (Directory replace with file content and it doesn't have file type)
```

**Code:**

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

 val Array(environment,customer, typesoftables, clientid, filedate) = args.take(5)

 val S3Path: String = customer + "/" + typesoftables + "/" + "clientid=" + clientid + "/" + "date=" + filedate + "/"

 val sourcefile : String = "gs://XXXX_-abc_account2621//abc_account2621_activity_20170618_20170619_034412_573362513.csv.gz"

 val destination: String = "s3n://S3bucketname/" + S3Path

 println(sourcefile)
 println(destination)

 val filepaths: Array[String] = Array(sourcefile, destination)  

 executeDistCp(filepaths)

 }

 def executeDistCp(filepaths : Array[String]) {
val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()

conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl","com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", "XXXX-XXXX")
conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile","/tmp/XXXXX.json")
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "XXXXXXXXXXXX")
conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")    
conf.set("mapreduce.application.classpath","$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
,/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*,/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf,/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*,/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*,/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*,/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-hadoop-goodies.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/cloudwatch-sink/lib/*,/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*,/tmp/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar")
conf.set("HADOOP_CLASSPATH","$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/tmp/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar")


val outputDir: Path = new Path(filepaths(1))
outputDir.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputDir, true)

val distCp: DistCp = new DistCp(conf,null)
ToolRunner.run(distCp, filepaths)

}
}
```

Comment: Just to eliminate some factors: Could you state whether the problem also occurs in these situations: 1. You run the command with the *, but only 1 file happens to exist in the relevant location 2. You copy from and to google storage 3. You copy from and to s3 -- Also, is only the display of the file weird, or are you also unable to use it?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin when run the code with the complete path for example gs://XXXX_-abc_account2621//abc_account2621_activity_20170618_20170619_034412_573362513.csv.gz that is only one file name, i am doing copy from GCP to S3

Comment: Your comment seems to describe what you already mentioned in the post. The points in my comment were suggestions to try other things, to see whether some root causes could be eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding below code the above issue is fixed

Code

```
 val makeDir: Path = new Path(filepaths(1))
 makeDir.getFileSystem(conf).mkdirs(makeDir)
```